# cannot run helloworld in Google app engine launcher

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Google App Engine Launcher suddenly not working when running any app, it works well yesterday.

**Error produced:**

```
     wi2013-01-15 14:56:52 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', 'C:\\Users\\Lawrence\\Documents\\guestbook-2']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 166, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 41, in <module>
    import mimetypes
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflict with this version of Python.
2013-01-15 14:56:52 (Process exited with code 1)
```

When you google this error, a lot of solution telling you to change the
`System/ User Environment` Variable to add `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts; C:\Python27\Lib;  C:\Python27\libs;`  etc, remove or add User Variable etc. All those trick not work for me.

I didn't install `python25`. Those programme refer to it and using import _socket are google app engine launcher itself or Google Drive, I have stopped my Google Drive already as people found this may cause problem. so I guess this `GAE` conflicted itself when some error happen inside it. The clue is I got another error in google app launcher log,`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log`
I'm using win 7 64 bits, `GAE 1.7.4`, `Python 2.7.3`

Comment: Those Environment Variable Tricks does not work for me.....

Comment: workaround for me was to not use the launcher and use the command line tools, seems ok so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `app.yaml`

you should have:

```
runtime: python
```

replace with:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
```

Pay attention to threadsafe:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#threadsafe

Other setting of `app.yaml`
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Required_Elements

If you start from Python 2.5 please read:
https:// developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#appyaml